# Is Category in Objective C and Default Methods in Java 8 equivalent?

Tags: java, objective-c

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695887/can-java-do-something-like-category-in-objective-c) but that doesn't discuss about default methods.

In objective C [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) lets you extend existing class by adding behaviour (even if you don't have original implementation source code) and makes it available to all instances of the original class. In Java 8 [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) were introduced which enabled to add new functionality to the interfaces of libraries. Are they equivalent to each other? If not, how they are different?